# How to build a simple search form in flask using mysqldb

Tags: python, html, mysql, flask, flask-wtforms

I have been trying to build a search form , to read isbn , author , year and title from the database that i have created locally using mysqldb.
Even tho i pondered along several websites , trying out tutorials to make it happen , I cannot find an optimum way to do this. Right now What i have done is this.
Python Code

```
@app.route('/search_results/<query>', methods = ['GET','POST'])
@is_logged_in
def search_results(query):
    cur=mysql.connection.cursor()
    likeString = "'%%" + query + "%%'"
    result = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM books WHERE %s  LIKE %s;", (query, likeString)) 
    if result > 0:
        data  = cur.fetchall()
    return render_template('search_results.html' , data = search)
    else:
        error = 'Nothing found'
        return render_template('dashboard.html' , error = error)
    return render_template('dashboard.html')




@app.route('/dashboard')
@is_logged_in
def dashboard():
  search = SearchForm(request.form)
if request.method == 'POST':
    select = form.select.data
    search = form.search.data
    query = select + search
    return redirect((url_for('search_results', query = query)))
return render_template('dashboard.html', form = search)
```

and my html code as follows:-

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block body %}
<h1>Dashboard <small>Welcome {{session.username}}</small></h1>

{% from "includes/_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}

<form action="/search_results/{{form.select}}/{{form.search}}" method=post>

<dl>

{{ render_field(form.select) }}

<p>

{{ render_field(form.search) }}

</dl>

<p><input type=submit value=Search>

</form>
</div>
{% for message in get_flashed_messages() %}
<div class=flash>
{{ message }}
</div>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Ive created a seperated search_results.html as well , which does not contain anything except a header H1 that displays search as follows 
    `<h1>{{search}}</h1>`

Comment: Please include your library dependencies, as this helps others explore the problem also.

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen @Bendebaria 's pattern for `GET` and `POST` routes, but haven't tested so I can't confirm it doesn't work (although I suspect it won't if you have multiple routes defined that way). The official Flask docs (http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#http-methods) say to do it like this:

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/search', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def search():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return do_the_db_search()
    else:
        return show_the_search_form()
```

But, indeed like he says, you don't need the `redirect`, in fact you can just call a regular function as part of your existing routing then return a `render_template` within those.

Comment: @Bendebaria 's Pattern for GET and POST routes is actually a method to implement Flask Routes , Unfortunately since the searchForm is created outside , an error occurs. However calling the functions is a good option. Thank You

Comment: How do you get the content from the search form?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `redirect()`.
You can make process POST and GET separately, and all you need is to render. Something like:

```
search = SearchForm(request.form)
@app.route('/dashboard')
@is_logged_in

def get():
    return render_template('dashboard.html', form = self.search)

def post():
    select = form.select.data
    search = form.search.data
    query = select + self.search
    return render_template('search_results', result = result)
```